# LDAP authentication using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, authentication, ldap

I have created a Restful API. I am using in here LDAP authentication. Our company has an LDAP directory server and I am using the below method `as utility` in my `service layer`.

This is my LDAP authentication method, which I am using this method as a utility in my service layer.

```
    public Map<String, Object> authenticate(String user, String pass) {
    String returnedAtts[] = {"sn", "givenName", "name", "userPrincipalName", "displayName", "memberOf"};
    String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=" + user + "))";
    // Create the search controls
    SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
    // Specify the search scope
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "SSL");
    LdapContext ctxGC = null;
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = null;
    Attributes attrs = null;
    SearchResult sr = null;
    NamingEnumeration<?> ne = null;
    Attribute attr = null;

    try {
        ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        if (ctxGC != null) {
            answer = ctxGC.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
            if (answer != null) {
                while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                    sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                    attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                    if (attrs != null) {
                        amap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        ne = attrs.getAll();
                        attr = (Attribute) ne.next();
                        amap.put(attr.getID(), attr.get());
                        ne.close();
                    }
                    ctxGC.close();         // Close and clean up
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Answer from domen controller is null!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Login or Password is wrong! ");
        }

    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+ex.toString());
    } finally {
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return amap;
}
```

This is my service layer class and I am making utility class as an injection that can be used authentication method as you know. When I send a request in swagger or postman username and password, given the values that come from the request, I persist them into to database of the table. but before persisting, the authentication method controls my username and password. if the password or username is not correct I return an error response to the client otherwise I return a success response to the client. In both situations, I insert given values to the database of the table from the request.

```
@Override
    public Optional<ResponseEntity<? extends ResponseDto>> login(String username, String password, String type) {

//Is there any method or feature that spring boot provides us instead of the method you see here?
        Map<String, Object> authenticate = this.controlDomainLogin.authenticate(username, password);
//Is there any method or feature that spring boot provides us instead of the method you see here?


        if (authenticate != null) {
            DomainLogin domainLogin = new DomainLogin();
            domainLogin.setUsername(username);
            domainLogin.setType(type);
            domainLogin.setLogDate(new Date());
            ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> responseDtoResponseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(new SuccessResponseDto(SUCCESS_OPERATION.getMessage(), SUCCESS_OPERATION.getCode(), authenticate), HttpStatus.OK);
            domainLogin.setResponse(Objects.requireNonNull(responseDtoResponseEntity.getBody()).getMessage() + "," + responseDtoResponseEntity.getBody().getCode());
            this.domainLoginRepository.save(domainLogin);
            return Optional.of(responseDtoResponseEntity);
        } else {
            DomainLogin domainLogin = new DomainLogin();
            domainLogin.setUsername(username);
            domainLogin.setType(type);
            domainLogin.setLogDate(new Date());
            ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> responseDtoResponseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponseDto(WRONG_USERNAME.getMessage(), WRONG_USERNAME.getCode()), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            domainLogin.setResponse(Objects.requireNonNull(responseDtoResponseEntity.getBody()).getMessage() + "," + responseDtoResponseEntity.getBody().getCode());
            domainLogin.setException(Objects.requireNonNull(responseDtoResponseEntity.getBody()).getMessage() + "," + responseDtoResponseEntity.getBody().getCode());
            this.domainLoginRepository.save(domainLogin);
            return Optional.of(responseDtoResponseEntity);
        }
    }
```

Now I don't need to use this method, instead, does spring boot itself have a similar method or any feature, just like the method I showed above? I mean I shouldn't use this method, instead, is there something spring boot gave us that does the same thing?

The same operations will be repeated, but the difference is that I will delete the method that I wrote in java and use the spring boot's LDAP authentication method instead.

If it is the class I have shown below, when I run the project, the login page that spring has given by default appears, when I type my username and password there, it performs the validation process successfully, if it fails, it gives the following warning.

```
ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${ad.domain}")
    private String AD_DOMAIN;

    @Value("${ad.url}")
    private String AD_URL;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN, AD_URL);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        return provider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Spring Data Ldap.
Just map Java class with Ldap Entry, that way you will also be able to do CRUD operations on Ldap.

Create one LdapUserService which extends UserDetail from Spring security.

And then use this LdapUserService in Spring security configurations.

Now you can perform authentication, authorization along with CRUD operations.

Comment: Do you know a link about it that you can share?